# How to download to england

Tags: installation

when i go to install blender (https://www.blender.org/download/) ( scroll to the bottom) it doesn't give me and option to download for England.

Comment: you can download form any of the options given

Comment: You'll just have to download from one of those other options. It's not "for" any of those places, it's "from". It just means it'll take longer.

Answer (score 5):

If you carefully look while hovering the mouse, you see a text saying "Choose mirror". This means that the software can be downloaded from the US and from 3 servers in europe (Netherlands and Germany) either one should be fine for you.

[image]